# Transfer from Multisig into normal address

Tags: transaction, iota-network, tangle, legacy-protocol, signing

I am following the example described here:

https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.java/blob/master/jota/src/test/java/jota/IotaMultisigTest.java

I put funds into a multisig. Now I want to move that funds out of the multisig address. Here is what I do:

```
private static final String TEST_SEED1 = "LRVLBLWMQWKDTDHDKTWXDDPUUECFSLIZPFXCSVHWOQQMG9GBMKRZSBHXFXYBENDHQSLUCNFCRHJTDRIED";
private static final String TEST_SEED2 = "BZOYLCAQGGAO9QI9HLWVXWQFZABMLFUCDPVZRYIBYGITEVWMVYVVYZPEJZFVCMVDERYRBPEUFXWDKLBBE";

private static final String REMAINDER_ADDRESS = "NZRALDYNVGJWUVLKDWFKJVNYLWQGCWYCURJIIZRLJIKSAIVZSGEYKTZRDBGJLOA9AWYJQB9IPWRAKUC9FBDRZJZXZG";
private static final String RECEIVE_ADDRESS = "GJQRMFGLIEQ9NKRKUUTGEZS9QEKERPLXPVMH9EYOPNDIWKHAWJEVPWXDUBEX9JXLAIAOWSUGJZCFBUVYX";
private static final String TEST_TAG = "JOTASPAM9999999999999999999";

private static String HOST = "13.58.231.155";
private static String PORT = "14265";
private static IotaAPI iotaAPI;
private static final String PROTOCOL = "http";



public static void main(String[] args) throws ArgumentException {
    iotaAPI = new IotaAPI.Builder().protocol(PROTOCOL).host(HOST).port(PORT).build();

       Multisig ms = new Multisig();

       String digestOne = ms.getDigest(TEST_SEED1, 3, 0);
       String initiatedMultisigDigests = ms.addAddressDigest(digestOne, "");
       System.out.println(initiatedMultisigDigests);
       String digestTwo = ms.getDigest(TEST_SEED2, 3, 0);
       String finalMultisigDigests = ms.addAddressDigest(digestTwo, initiatedMultisigDigests);
       String multiSigAddress = ms.finalizeAddress(finalMultisigDigests);

       List<Transfer> transfers = new ArrayList<>();
       transfers.add(new Transfer(RECEIVE_ADDRESS, 1, "", TEST_TAG));
       List<Transaction> trxs = iotaAPI.initiateTransfer(6, multiSigAddress, REMAINDER_ADDRESS, transfers, false);

       Bundle bundle = new Bundle(trxs, trxs.size());
       bundle = ms.addSignature(bundle, multiSigAddress, ms.getKey(TEST_SEED1, 0, 3));
       bundle = ms.addSignature(bundle, multiSigAddress, ms.getKey(TEST_SEED2, 0, 3));


       List<String> trytes = new ArrayList<>();
       for (Transaction tx : bundle.getTransactions()) {
            trytes.add(tx.toTrytes());
       }
       trxs = iotaAPI.sendTrytes(trytes.toArray(new String[trytes.size()]), 9,14,null);
}
```

This code executes fine and the transaction get posted to the tangle. You can see it here:

https://iotasear.ch/transaction/WSWISHOSHC9GVITFLEPGYUIMQNUMZFHXVBQPILNIYYJYCZPNIXGBLLILYXYPPCHIPVICZWPPURGQ99999

The big challenge is that this transaction doesn't seem valid. It is never confirmed  and it does not even appear in the light wallet. Something is off that I can't figure out. I guess the question is mainly how to properly use the produced bundle so that it is properly processed by the network.

One thing I notice is that the signature of the bundle is 99999..9999; which means that it is empty.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems that (also on thetangle.org) only one of the 7 transactions of your bundle arrived. Incomplete bundles will not get confirmed, so make sure you get all transactions of your bundle posted.

Answer (score 0):

quite late - but, I believe, your error occurred, because you did not reverse the order of your String array.

try a *Collections.reverse(trytes)* before sending the tx to the tangle with api.sendtrytes(). That most likely also explains, why thetangle.org did not properly pick up you bundle.

a good example can be found here (though in javascript): https://gist.github.com/domschiener/23b580d1bf4053c735c9e20721f8087b